# Launch java command from in_exec Fluentd plugin

Tags: java, bash, exec, fluentd, td-agent

I have any problems to configure `Fluentd`; I want call `in_exec` plugin to launch Linux bash script that call a jar but it doesn't work.
My code:

```
  <source>
    @type exec
    format none
    tag none
    command sh /var/tmp/script.sh
    run_interval 5m
  </source>
```

And my script is:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  java -jar example.jar
```

I don't understad where I wrong; if I change script (for example to create a file) all it's OK but if I use java command it doesn't work.

Please help me!
Thanks

Comment: Where is your jar located? Try to use absolute path of the jar to run in the script.

Comment: Jar is located at /home/out/example.jar; I try to absolute path but it doesn't work. If launch script from command line outside Fluetd work correctly. Have you any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update your script with the absolute path to the jar in the sh file. Otherwise, there may be a problem when executing script in different locations and it will fail to find the jar.

```
  #!/bin/bash
  java -jar /hom/{User}/{Path to Jar}example.jar
```